# jQuery first element that contain a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select a first element that contain a string.

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
     $('.rte:contains(' + arr[i] + '):first').css('background', 'red');
}
```

This doesn't work properly because it's selecting a 2 elements: an element that contains my string AND first element. I want to select only the 2nd element, because it contains a string. 
I have no idea where is the bug.

edit:
Also if i use only 
    $('.rte:contains(' + arr[i] + ')').css('background', 'red');
it's selecting all elements, even this which not contain a string

Comment: @blgt i can't do that, becouse sometimes a first element can be correct one
KrisKrause more than 1000 elements

Comment: @MPMOZ My bad, that was wrong. Another thing: is the `++1` a typo in the question?

Comment: @blgt nope, there is a ++i, my bad

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class='root'>
    <li>dd</li>
    <li>dd</li>
    <li>dd</li>
    <li>dd</li>
    <li>dd</li>
</ul>


$(".root li:first-child").css('background', 'red');
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the last array element. It was empty. So the :contains("") was always true for the first element

Comment: this should be a comment.. put such replies in comments or update your question..